# What to do when in a couple, the woman leaves Islam to be non believer?

Tags: fiqh, nikah

Salam,

What if a muslim couple get married, and somehow, the woman leaves Islam to be atheist ?

Knowing that It is not allowed to get married to a non believer woman.

Thank you

Comment: Divorce. If she foraked Islam upon marriage, you have no right to reamin married with a disbeliever. As a male, you're only allowed to marry women who are people of the book.

Answer (score 0):

Via consensus, men are allowed to marry women 'of the book', being Jewish and Christian women. Not the other way around. So you would have to divorce her.

You should look at this Quranic verse, too:

> Allah says: “Do not marry idolatresses (al mushrikāt) till they believe, and certainly a believing maid is better than an idolatress even though she would please you, and do not marry idolaters (al Mushrikīn) till they believe (hata yūminū), and certainly a believing slave is better than an idolater, even though he would please you. These invite to the Fire, and Allah invites to the Garden and to forgiveness by His grace, and makes clear His revelations to mankind so that they may remember.”Qur’an 2:221.

***CONCLUSION***

It is haram for all. You cannot marry atheists as a man or a woman.

I AM NO SCHOLAR. I am new so there may be mistakes. Please correct me in the 'Comments' area If there are any.

Comment: Kindly cite your source that there is a consensus that "men are allowed to marry women as disbelievers". Only women among the people of the book (Jews\Christians) are permitted to be married, not apostates and not atheists.

Comment: I believe I misinterpreted it. When I see 'People of the book', I think of Islam, not Judaism and Christianity. When I see online that men marrying Jewish / Christian women, I do not see a difference between a Jew or a Hindu. That was on me. Thank you!

Comment: I have edited the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer is still incorrect. The question is specifically asking about an atheist woman. Mentioning the ruling for Jews\Christians is irrelevant and misleading.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have changed the conclusion to say that marrying an atheist woman is haraam, to give the answer more clearly. I am pretty new, but not very new to this service. If there are more mistakes, please point them out.